# How to get a $scope object to an angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have an object that I am modifying on `$rootScope` where I am "storing" my last search parameters. Currently I have the values `returnType`, rows, and query hard coded.  I would like to those just be references to the object on `$rootScope`.

How can I reference an object on `$rootScope` in a service?

```
angular.module('myApp.services').factory("SearchService", function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/do/search", {}, {
        query: {method: "GET", isArray: false, params: {
            returnType: 'json',
            rows: 25,
            query:'bob*'
        }}
    })
```

Comment: there are ways to get that data from $rootScope, but i would suggest against storing data on $rootScope

Comment: It would be better to store that data on another service rather than on $rootScope.

Comment: As suggested, it's better that you store these references in their own service, but if you must do it this way, you can just inject `$rootScope` into your factory.

Comment: @zmanc do you want to be able change that bit only ? : "query:'bob*'"

Comment: sylwester, there are other things that I want to change as well, that was just a simplified example.   ivarni or scarlz, can you submit response as a answer so I can give rep.  I ended up going with a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of storing things like this in localStorage. I don't want to mod the above answer, because it's perfectly valid and it's good code. Thanks for Ed B's contribution there.

On the other hand, there's a security implication - you're storing potentially sensitive query text in a relatively easy-to-access region, not that great for users on library/Internet cafe computers. Most people are used to clearing cookies, but that doesn't wipe out localStorage data so you'd either have to provide a mechanism for this, or suggest what, that all your users use "Incognito Mode"? I prefer to use things like localStorage for caching *app* data, but not *user* data unless you're sure it's not sensitive.

Only you can decide if this is important. But since your original question was just about how to use $rootScope as a dumping ground, here's an answer for that specific piece. Just inject it into your service/factory/etc:

```
angular.module('myApp.services').factory("SearchService", function($rootScope, $resource) {
// You now have access to $rootScope here
return $resource("/do/search", {}, {
    query: {method: "GET", isArray: false, params: {
        returnType: 'json',
        rows: 25,
        query: $rootScope.query
    }}
});
```

A couple of quick comments:

1. Why call it a service and make it a factory? :) There isn't really an efficiency difference and the code might be a little simpler if you actually made it a full service.
2. If you make it a real service, you probably don't need $rootScope any more. With a service, you can create a method that can be called from elsewhere... and then you can accept parameters directly from the caller. So the caller could send data right to the search function and then process its results. Simple!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above, if you want to store a user's recent data then this should be done using a service - specifically in `LocalStorage`.

I would suggest implementing a service as follows:

```
myApp.factory('localStorageService', function() {
    return {
        get : function (key) {
            return localStorage.getItem(key);
        },
        set : function (key, val) {
            return localStorage.setItem(key, val);
        },
        clearAll : function () {
            localStorage.clear();
        }
    };
};
```

To store the user's recent search data, for instance from within a Controller:

```
myApp.controller('homeCtrl', function(localStorageService){
    localStorageService.set('query', 'bob*');
});
```

And to retrieve it:

```
localStorageService.get('query');
```

And, of course, to clear the `localStorage` altogether:

```
localStorageService.clearAll();
```

---

If you prefer, there are also [existing module's out there](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) for localStorage access, including fallbacks.

Comment: that is a very different answer than what the above were suggesting. Interesting solution though.

Comment: I believe that they were alluding to services along these lines. Either way, for the sake of User Experience it's good practice to implement localStorage if you intend to store a user's data for a short period of time. That way, if they leave your site (purposely or accidentally) and then return, their search history remains intact.